# Jackson stream sends incomplete JSON objects

Tags: java, json, stream, jackson

I would like to send JSON to a socket and process it with JavaScript. But unfortunately the JSON-Object is not send in it's entirety. After the object `data` was written to the outputstream the server receives the JSON-Object, not waiting for anything that comes after.

**How I write to the socket**

```
jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
jsonGenerator.writeStringField("from", from);
jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("data", data);
jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
```

**What the server handler receives at one point**

```
{"from":"me","data":{"one":1,"two":2}
```

As you can see the last `}` was not written. If I were to write the `data` object before the `from` field, the server would get this:

```
{"data":{"one":1,"two":2}
```

The rest of the JSON object will be send but not as one entity which makes it hard to parse at the server.

The `JsonGenerator` was created like this

```
JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = (new JsonFactory()).createGenerator(socket.getOutputStream());
jsonGenerator.setCodec(new ObjectMapper());
```

I suspect it has something to do with codec settings.

**Server side**

Is a simple NodeJS which logs the data coming through the socket.

```
net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.on("data", function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

You can see in the console that the JSON-Object is send through 2 distinct events. It also throws errors when I try to parse the `data` coming in because some of the object is missing.

**EDIT**

I noticed that sometimes it would send the whole JSON-Object, but only 1 out 20 times, if at all. Sending just string fields and number fields works flawlessly.

Comment: "What the server handler receives at one point" can you record what the other end is sending.

Comment: Yes I can, it is a simple NodeJS server which logs the incoming data to the console. I added the code above.

Comment: I meant, can you log than the Java side is send, not what the Node.js is receiving.

Answer (score 2):

I found you have to call either `flush()` or `close()` is it appears to buffer some of the data.

From the Javadoc for flush()

```
/**
 * Method called to flush any buffered content to the underlying
 * target (output stream, writer), and to flush the target itself
 * as well.
 */
@Override
public abstract void flush() throws IOException;
```

Comment: Why would it buffer after parsing the `data` object? I flushed the `JsonGenerator` and the `socket.getOutputStream()` after I send everything down the stream, but it didn't help.